# Microsoft SysVAD Virtual Audio Device Driver (SYSVAD) cannot work

Tags: windows, audio, driver, wdk

This driver (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/audio/sysvad) is provided by Microsoft. And in its README, the last part, it says:

> Locate an MP3 or other audio file on the target computer and
>   double-click to play it. Then in the Sound dialog box, verify that
>   there is activity in the volume level indicator associated with the
>   SYSVAD (with APO Extensions) driver.

But in my target computer, the volume level indicator associated with the SYSVAD (with APO Extensions) driver does not change at all. And the target computer does not make any sound.

The same case to the mic, when set default mic to any of the sysvad mic array, the mic volume level will not change at all.

In my understanding, sysvad driver is virtual driver. So it will not really work. But why Microsoft README says: there is **activity** in the volume level indicator associated with the SYSVAD (with APO Extensions) driver.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on SysVad too and sure it works, for Mic you can test with vlc player
Try to open the virtual mic from VLC and then you will hear sound,  it's a sin wave generated by driver itself

Comment: VLC -> Media -> Stream -> Capture Device -> Audio device name: any SYSVAD mic, then I can hear sound. Is it right? @Gerry

Comment: @Gerry When you say it works, do you know if your sound is going through any of the APOs? I have also installed the driver, but not sure if APOs are running. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Danijel, sorry for the late reply, not sure it is going through APO or not, I didn't pay attention to apo at all

Answer (score 3):

The SYSVAD documentation leaves a lot to be desired.  You won't see any activity in the volume level indicator, and you won't hear anything, since the only thing the rendering endpoints do is save a copy of the audio output to file (look for `C:\STREAM_HOST_*.wav` files).

The capture endpoints (including the "loopback" pins) generate constant sine-wave signals, which you can see if you use an app to record them, and then view them in a sound editor/viewer or play them back out to a real device.

Comment: Very usefull comment, thanks for this. I was trying to "hear" something out from my test laptop, but it remained silent. No I see a bunch of `C:\STREAM_HOST_*.wav` files. Yes, documentation could be better :-)...

Comment: Richard, do you know a way to turn on/off the APO components? I have installed the driver per instructions on the page, but I am not sure if the sound is passing through any of the 3 APO components. How do I discover that?

Comment: @Danijel I tried a few times to turn on/off the APO components, but couldn't get them to work.  In my project I decided it was better to add a custom IOCTL for accessing the audio ring buffers, and did the audio processing in a normal user-space process (app or service).  To check if sound is passing through any part of your driver, including APOs, I recommend logging [WPP trace events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/wpp-software-tracing) in your APO component code and see if the events appear at runtime.